# Multi Dimension array to convert in string in php

Tags: php, laravel

```
Array ( [11] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => Attempt ) [ 12] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => None ) [ 13] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => None ) [ 14] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => None ) [ 15] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => None ) [ 16] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => None ) )
```

This is my array but i want in below STRING format:

```
11=>A=>Attempt,12=>0=>None,13=>0=>None,14=>0=>None,15=>0=>None,16=>0=>None

  1. $keys=array_keys($total_answer)
   2.     for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
    3.   {
      4.      for($j=0;$j<count($total_answer[$keys[$i]]);$j++)
        5.    {
          6.     echo $total_answer[$keys[$i]][$j]
           7. //Here I am getting confuse to make string 

Thank You In Advance:)
```

Comment: and what is your try?

Comment: I have tried all the way possible using foreach and for....But didnt get expected outout

Comment: then post that foreach try and ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it,

```
<?php
$array = array ( "11" => array ( "0" => "A" ,"1" => "Attempt" ) ,"12" => array ( "0" => 0, "1" => "None" ) ,"13" => array ( "0" => 0, "1" => "None" ) ,"14" => array ( "0" => 0 ,"1" => "None" ), "15" => array ( "0" => 0, "1" => "None" ), "16" => array ( "0" => 0, "1" => "None" ) );
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $expected[] = $key.'=>'.$value[0].'=>'.$value[1];
}
echo implode(',',$expected);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO**: https://3v4l.org/TDb0A

Answer (score 1):

One foreach is enough

```
    $out = [];
    foreach ($total_answer as $k=>$v)
    {
        array_unshift($v, $k);
        $out[] = implode('=>', $v);
    }
    echo implode(',', $out);
```